# VueJs and VueResource, removing header fields from a Ajax request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

When I instantiate a Vuejs **(2.2.6)** and Vue-resource **(1.2.1)**, I set the header authorization with the following code, this way I can authorize all requests to my API:

```js
Vue.http.headers.common.AUTHORIZATION = 'BEARER ...';
```

However, I want to make a request for a third party API, and I do not want the `Authorization` field to be sent. Additionally, this API does not allow you to use this authorization header.

```js
let CEP = '';

this.$http.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + CEP + '/json')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.headers);
    });
```

This way the authorization field is sent with the header, on **Access-Control-Request-Headers**:

[image: Request header]

I tried to remove some header fields with the following codes, without success.

```js
this.$http.headers.common.AUTHORIZATION = null;
this.$http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = null;

this.$http.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + CEP + '/json')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.headers);
    });
```

In the `vue-resource` documentation, there is the possibility of inserting an object to force the request configuration, but the documentation isn't  complete.

```js
this.$http.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + CEP + '/json', {
   ...here...
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers);
});
```

Is there any way to remove the *Authorization* field, or any other field  from a given request?
Thanks.

*** UPDATED ***

By using the interceptors (as in the below sample) **I can edit** the request but **I can not delete** a particular field.

```js
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {

    const viacep = request.url.includes('viacep.com.br');

    if (viacep) {
        request.headers.set('AUTHORIZATION', 'TRY THIS');
    }

    next(response => {});
});
```

[image: editing request]

Try to Delete:

```js
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {

    const viacep = request.url.includes('viacep.com.br');

    if (viacep) {
        request.headers.delete('AUTHORIZATION');
    }

    next(response => {});
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an [interceptor](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#interceptors), inspect the request, and remove the header if needed.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {

  const removeAuthHeaders = request.url.includes("viacep.com.br");

  if (removeAuthHeaders){
    request.headers.delete('Access-Control-Allow-Headers')
    request.headers.delete('AUTHORIZATION')
  }
  else {
    request.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', <value>)
    request.headers.set('AUTHORIZATION', <value>)
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: It's unbelievable, I can set/modify but I can not delete!

Comment: @ThiagoPereira I think it may be because you assigned them to `.common`. Can you *not* do that and just assign them as I did above?

Comment: The `request.headers.common` inside interceptor is `undefined`, I'm using you example, when I try to delete the token nothing happens. Please see the above prints. Your think this is wrong: `Vue.http.headers.common.AUTHORIZATION = 'Bearer: ...';`

Comment: @ThiagoPereira I'm trying to say, if you have run this line somewhere, `Vue.http.headers.common.Authorization = <whatever>`, then it **cannot** be removed. If you do *not* do that, and just add the authorization header *only* in the interceptor when needed, then you should be ok.